# Issues with enums usage in different class C#

Tags: c#, enums

```
class GSM 
{

    private string name;
    private string manufacturer;
    private string owner;
    private double price;

    public string Name  
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }

    public string Manufacturer
    {
        get { return this.manufacturer; }
    }

    public string Owner
    {
        get { return this.owner; }
        set { this.owner = value; }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    public GSM(string name, string manu) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.manufacturer = manu;
    }

    public GSM(string name, string manu, string owner, double price, Battery battery, Display display)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.manufacturer = manu;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Owner: " + Owner + "\nModel: " + Name + "\nManufacturer: " + Manufacturer + "\nPrice: " + Price + "\n";
    }     
}
```

Two types of classes

```
class Battery
{
    private ushort hoursIdle;
    private ushort hoursTalk;
    private _BatteryType batteryType;
    
    public _BatteryType BatteryType
    {
        get { return this.batteryType; }
    }

    public enum _BatteryType { LiLon, NiMH, NiCd } 
    
    public ushort HoursIdle 
    {
        get { return hoursIdle; }
    }

    public ushort HoursTalk 
    {
        get { return hoursTalk; }
    }

    public Battery(ushort hoursIdle, ushort hoursTalk, _BatteryType batteryType)
    {
        this.hoursIdle = hoursIdle;
        this.hoursTalk = hoursTalk;
        this.batteryType = batteryType;
    }              
}
```

My main

```
static void TestDataArray()
{
        GSM test = new GSM("IPhone", "Apple");
        GSM test2 = new GSM("IPhone XI", "Apple", "x", 13000,new Battery(10,5,Battery._BatteryType.LiLon),new Display(20,1000,Display._Display.LCD));
        GSM test3 = new GSM("Samsung Galaxy S20", "Samsung", "y", 11000, new Battery(10, 5, Battery._BatteryType.LiLon), new Display(20, 2000,Display._Display.AMOLED));
        GSM[] MobileArray = new GSM[3] { test,test2,test3 };

        foreach (object o in MobileArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
}
```

Issue: I want to get the get the enums data "LCD" in iphone and "AMOLED" on Samsung, Cannot put it on override to string method. Tried to create a new instance in the GSM class but getting default value. Tried to call the Battery class and then the enum list but forces me to choice a value.

Comment: You pass a Battery and a Display object to the GMS constructor, but do not store it in a field. Is this your problem?

Comment: Cheeers ! :) thanks alot mate

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear on your question but I saw a couple of things that will tidy up your code and possibly fix your issue.

Changing the `Battery` class to Public will make the enum accessible.

Changed the variables to having a single source with a `public get` and `private set` rather than separate `public` and `private` variables as well as a couple name changes to make it easier to use and read.

And added a default value for the `IsBatteryType` of `IsBatteryType.NotSet`

```
public class Battery
{
    public enum BatteryType { NotSet, LiLon, NiMH, NiCd } 
    
    public BatteryType IsBatteryType { get; private set;} = BatteryType.NotSet;
    
    public ushort HoursIdle { get; private set; }

    public ushort HoursTalk { get; private set; }

    public Battery(ushort hoursIdle, ushort hoursTalk, BatteryType batteryType)
    {
        this.HoursIdle = hoursIdle;
        this.HoursTalk = hoursTalk;
        this.IsBatteryType = batteryType;
    }              
}
```

I hope this helps and solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for taking time to answer my question.

Issue is now sloved!

```
 class GSM
    {
        private string name;
        private string manufactor;
        private string owner;
        private double price;
        private Battery battery;
        private Display display;

        public Battery Battery
        { 
            get { return this.battery; }
            set { this.battery = value; }
        }
        public Display Display
        {
            get { return this.display; }
            set { this.display = value; }
        }
        public string Name  
        {
            get { return this.name; }
        }
        public string Manufactor
        {
            get { return this.manufactor; }
        }
        public string Owner
        {
            get { return this.owner; }
            set { this.owner = value; }
        }
        public double Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }
        }
        public GSM(string name, string manu) 
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.manufactor = manu;
            
        }
        public GSM(string name, string manu, string owner, double price,Battery battery,Display display)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.manufactor = manu;
            this.owner = owner;
            this.price = price;
            this.battery = battery;
            this.display = display;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Owner: " + Owner + "\nModel: " + Name + "\nManufactor: " + Manufactor + "\nPrice: " + Price + "\nSpecification: \nBatteryType: " + battery.BatteryType + "\nDisplayType: " + display.Displays;
        }
```

I created new fields so my constructor was able to get the values. I also now looked at my varible names to clear things up. great thanks to akaBase and Klaus Gutter